# Vaadin:Compilation error after upgrading 8.13.3

Tags: groovy, vaadin, vaadin8

I’m working on upgrading our application vaadin version from 7.7.24 to 8.13.3. We’ve completed all the dependency issues but i'm getting two compilation errors.

```
1. ERROR in /Users/Desktop/Codebase/unlimited/im/im-ui/src/main/java/com/io/im/looker/ssot/LookerScheduleJson.groovy (at line 1)
        package com.io.im.looker.ssot
        ^
The type groovy.lang.GroovyObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
----------
2. ERROR in /Users/Desktop/Codebase/unlimited/im/im-ui/src/main/java/com/io/im/looker/ssot/LookerScheduleJson.groovy (at line 1)
        package com.io.im.looker.ssot
        ^
The type groovy.lang.MetaClass cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Here is my main pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.iodine.imc</groupId>
    <artifactId>imc</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>imc-core</module>
        <module>imc-restapi</module>
        <module>imc-ui</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <vaadin.version>8.13.3</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>build.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>build.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.0-01</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>${groovy.version}-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>groovy-vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-vaadin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                    <!--<dependency>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                        <version>2.11.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    </dependency>-->
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.groovy</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                        <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Abstract*.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>true</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suppressionFile>owasp-false-positives.xml</suppressionFile>
                        <failBuildOnCVSS>8</failBuildOnCVSS>
                        <assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>false</assemblyAnalyzerEnabled>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my my ui pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>imc</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.iodine.imc</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>imc-ui</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR12</spring-cloud.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.13.3</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>8.13.3</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <vaadin4spring.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</vaadin4spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>imc-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-ext-security</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-addon-eventbus</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-addon-sidebar</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-addon-i18n</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-combobox-multiselect</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.16</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-sass-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-treegrid -->
<!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-treegrid</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.8</version>
        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>tableexport-for-vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.haijian</groupId>
            <artifactId>exporter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1G</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <!--<goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>-->
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>false</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

This was working fine with Vaadin 7 version. I've checked all possible ways to do dependency compatibility check but it didn't show any issues. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the dependency tree of the final pom?
Have you tried to add the missing jars?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, I didn't get any error.  Also when I tried commenting out ScheduleJson.groovy file the error is not showing up

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1045

Comment: What are "groovy.version" and "java.version" properties set to?  You don't need to supply "source" and "target" within plugin > configuration since you set "maven.compiler.source" and "maven.compiler.target" properties.  Also, I would expect to see the dependencies groovy-all and groovy-vaadin at the project level since they are not dependencies for the compiler, but for your project/sources.  https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin